# DropDownList displays Item - 1 (previous)

Tags: asp.net

I have two dropdown lists Category and SubCategory. When I select a particular category the SubCategory dropdown list populates the items based on the selected value of the Category. Then I save the selection in the database and everything works fine.

The values of the Category, SubCategory are loaded based on a query string (ProductID). When I revisit the page (with/without postback), the SubCategory shows the previous item! Maybe the problem is the need to add a default value=0, but by enabling the AppendDataBoundItems=True the items in the list are getting duplicated.

Any ideas?

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCategory" runat="server"  DataSourceID="dsDNN" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="CategoryID" AutoPostBack="True" AppendDataBoundItems="True" EnableViewState="True">
  <asp:ListItem Value="0">-- SELECT --</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsDNN" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SiteSqlServer %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [CategoryID], [Name] FROM [tCategory]"></asp:SqlDataSource>

 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSubcategory" runat="server"  DataSourceID="dsSubCat" DataTextField="Name"  DataValueField="SubCategoryID" EnableViewState="True" AutoPostBack="True">
 </asp:DropDownList>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsSubCat" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SiteSqlServer %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [SubCategoryID], [Name] FROM [tSubCategory] WHERE ([CategoryID] = @CategoryID)">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlCategory" Name="CategoryID" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just add an if statement around the code that populates the dropdown for the sub category. Use a condition that is only set to true when a selection is made in the first dropdown

Comment: can you give me an example?

Comment: Post the code you are using to populate both dropdowns

Comment: I would not populate my dropdown like that, it makes the code harder to follow for someone who has not worked on it before. I would populate it in the (vb?) page behind. Here is a link with instructions on how to do this http://www.dbtutorials.com/advanced/populatedropdown-vb/